# Redirect from @ExceptionHandler doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, redirect, exception

I have exception handler like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public classMyExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(MyRuntimeException.class)
    public String handleMyRuntimeException(MyRuntimeExceptionexception ex){
        LOGGER.info(ex.getMessage());
        return "redirect:/www.google.com";
    }
}
```

I execute http request, I see that Controller handles my request, then `MyRuntimeException` is throwing and `handleMyRuntimeException` method is invoking. but in postman I see that server returns 401 http status and I don't see www.google.com in response headers.

What do I wrong?

Comment: Could you try `return new ModelAndView("redirect:/www.google.com");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , Postman by default will automatically follow the redirect . What you get in the Postman is the response that is already redirected to `/www.google.com`. Go to setting to turn this off :

[image]

Second , `redirect:/www.google.com` is different from `redirect://www.google.com` 
. Assuming your server is `127.0.0.1:8080` :

- `redirect:/www.google.com`    --> redirect to
  `http://127.0.0.1:8080/www.google.com`
- `redirect://www.google.com` --> redirect to `http://www.google.com`

So you actually redirect back to your server and the 401 error that you received is probably due to your server 's access control.

Answer (score -2):

In my case it is working fine, please check:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(CustomRuntimeException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
    public ModelAndView handleCustomRuntimeException(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Exception ex) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("error");
        mav.addObject("error", "500");
        return mav;
        //return new ModelAndView("redirect:https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```